# Exchange Web Service with OAuth2 and Updating a users Calendar

Tags: azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices, azureportal

I'm working on creating a 3rd party application that will read/update a users office 365 calendar.  My code works fine with a user who in part of the same tenant as the application.  However, when I try to do the same thing with a users from a different office 365 account it doesn't work.  For example when I log in with the following it works:
[image]

This one doesn't work:

[image]

I have set them both up as owners within my azure.portal.com application.
[image]

The users have granted the application access to their calendars, but for some reason the one on a different tenant does not work.  Any idea?

Comment: You screen shot doesn't show the detail of permissions granted have you granted EWS.AccessAsUser.All ? This is the only permission that is valid in EWS the others ones you have listed will only work in the Graph. You can use https://jwt.io/ to see what actual permission are in the token your using in various enviroments

Comment: It seems that the second one is an Microsoft personal account. Why do you say it's a account from a different tenant? It's a guest user of another O365 tenant? Besides, can you provide the details of error message for the second one?

Comment: Allen,  I've tried with other office 365 accounts (russr in screen shot) and my hotmail account.  Both return a 401 - unauthorized when I try to create the meeting.  In the Azure portal log, for that user, it shows a Sign-in error code = 65001 with a failure reason of "Application X doesn't have permission to access application Y or the permission has been revoked. Or The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID X. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource. Or The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID..."

Comment: Glen, Thanks for getting back to me.  When I look at both users token's with https://jwt.ms/ I see the line "scp": "Calendars.ReadWrite.All EAS.AccessAsUser.All EWS.AccessAsUser.All", so I think it has that permission.